# Unable to delete some of the list elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get URLs of a particular website. I'm in the process of it. Can anyone help me? I'm able to delete some of the elements in the list(linkaddresses) after appending it. First i'm taking all urls from particular website (swiggy.com here). After i'm trying to delete list elements( linkaddresses)  starting with '/'. When i run the below programme, It is only deleting some of them. In programme itself i printed all the list (linkaddresses) elements before and after modification

below is code in python:

import urllib
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
def linkgetter(searchlink):
    pagesource = urllib.request.urlopen(searchlink)
    linkaddresses = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource,'lxml')
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        if link.get('href') == None:
            continue
        else:
            linkaddresses.append(link.get('href'))
    print(linkaddresses)
    for i in linkaddresses:
        if i.startswith('#'):
            linkaddresses.remove(i)
        elif i.startswith('/'):
            linkaddresses.append(searchlink+i)
            linkaddresses.remove(i)
    print('\n')
    print('\n')
    print('\n')

    print(linkaddresses)
linkgetter('https://www.swiggy.com')
```

Comment: As general advice, you should avoid modifying lists that you are looping through

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, modifying lists you are looping through is a bad idea! You can either populate a new list with the values, or list comprehension can be your friend here :)

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

I've broken your for loop into 2 comprehensions. First to filter out anything that starts with a `#`

```
linkaddresses = [x for x in linkaddresses if not x.startswith('#')]
```

Second to then append the link address to anything starting with a `/`

```
linkaddresses = [searchlink+x if x.startswith('/') else x for x in linkaddresses]
```

Full code is now

```
def linkgetter(searchlink):
    pagesource = urllib.request.urlopen(searchlink)
    linkaddresses = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource,'lxml')
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        if link.get('href') == None:
            continue
        else:
            linkaddresses.append(link.get('href'))
    print(linkaddresses)

    linkaddresses = [x for x in linkaddresses if not x.startswith('#')]
    linkaddresses = [searchlink+x if x.startswith('/') else x for x in linkaddresses]

    print('\n')
    print(linkaddresses)

linkgetter('https://www.swiggy.com')
```